# Parsing User Input to Determine Mathematical Function Type

Tags: python, python-3.x

Creating a program that accepts user input in the form of ax^n+bx+c where there are any number of exponents or terms. For example, 3x^2 and 4x^5+3x^2 are both valid inputs. I want to take that input and then re-create it so I can evaluate the given input for a series of values. So far, I've tried to locate the x-variables and then the characters nearby to test if it's an exponent. Can't seem to do that right however. Is there an easier way to do this? I have to use the standard python library.

```
choice = input("Enter a function\n")

for i in choice:
    if i == "x":
        ex = choice.find("x")
        ex = choice[ex+2]
        ex2 = choice.find("x")
        ex2 = choice[ex2+1]
        print(ex)
        print(ex2)
        if ex or ex2 == "+" or "-":
            ex3 = "kill me"
            print("STILL HERE")
        elif ex2 != "^":
            ex3 = "1"
            print('finally got here')
        else:
            ex3 = choice.find["x"]
            ex3 = choice[ex3+2]
        print(ex3)
    else:
        pass
```

My current attempts seem to reach the second if statement

```
if ex or ex2 == "+" or "-":
```

And I'm not sure why they trigger it because given an input such as 3x^2, there isn't even a + or -. As well, the find() method only looks for the first "x" so each time, I get the same term.

Ultimately, my goal is to "re-assemble" the user-inputted expression so I can iterate through it and calculate a series of values. I'm not sure if there's an easier way to do this.

Comment: Are you interested only in simple expressions with numbers, x, ^, + and no other characters? Specifically, no parentheses?

Comment: Correct. Will only be simple expressions.

Comment: Can you explain how your attempt doesn't work?

Comment: I have several problems right now. Any double digit exponent ruins it. And currently, I can't get past the second if statement. It prints "STILL HERE" if given an input such as 3x^2.

Comment: Please edit your question. Don't attempt to post code in comments.

Comment: I'm just looking for an easier way to take a user inputted expression and "re-assemble" it so to speak.

Comment: I think you mean `if (ex=="+" or ex=="-") or (ex2=="+" or ex2=="-"):`